# Mysql select one fields needs with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on mysql i have to one filed from db table in different three conditions

```
my db table user_pay
fields- username,amt,postingDate,category
```

i want result like

```
username  amtbeforedate  amtbetweendate amtcategory
john            500           1000          1200
```

conditions as per fields

```
where conditions- startdate, enddate, category
username
amtbeforedate= sum(amt) From user_pay WHERE postingDate >  startdate
amtbetweendate=sum(amt) From user_pay WHERE postingDate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate AND (category='paid' OR category='notpaid')
amtcategory =sum(amt) From user_pay WHERE postingDate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate AND (category='adjustment')
```

i want this result in single query.
i trying different example but not getting any result
query will only get called once per query not once per row

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question right you can apply the condition inside sum 
some thing like that

```
SUM(CASE WHEN postingDate > startdate THEN amt ELSE 0 END) as amtbeforedate
```

whole query goes like this

```
select 
 SUM(CASE WHEN postingDate > startdate THEN amt ELSE 0 END) as amtbeforedate
 SUM(CASE WHEN postingDate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate AND (category='paid' OR category='notpaid')
THEN amt ELSE 0 END) as amtbetweendate
 SUM(CASE WHEN postingDate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate AND (category='adjustment') THEN amt ELSE 0 END) as amtbeforedate
from user_pay
```

Hope it help